# Application of spike and slab for sampling from posterior distribution (bernoulli and beta)

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I think the gamma N term in the first equation relates to the spike and prior. However, I am unsure what the rhs of the first is used for? Further, I am unsure what the pie term of the second equation refers to and why it is modelled using a Beta distribution?

Note, this is using mcmc sampling.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your second and third questions first - $\pi_{\alpha j}^B$ is the probability that $\gamma_{ajk}^B = 1$; $\gamma_{ajk}^B$ is a binary variable whose distribution is Bernoulli, and the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) has a single parameter, the probability of the random variable taking on the value $1$. Often we choose prior distributions on probabilities to be Beta distributions, since they naturally model variables that take on values in $(0,1)$ and their functional form results in certain mathematical conveniences ([Conjugacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)) when calculating posterior distributions.

Now for your first question.  The spike-and-slab distributions consist of a discrete spike at a single point, i.e., a particular value that can be realized with a non-zero probability as with a discrete distribution, and a continuous distribution, typically (but not always) centered at the location of the spike.   In this case, the spike is at $0$, hence the notation $I_0$, where $I_a$ is the indicator function that takes on the value $1$ if the value of the random variable $= a$ and $0$ otherwise. The probability mass associated with this spike, i.e., the probability that the random variable exactly equals zero, is $(1-\gamma_{ajk}^B)$.   If the r.v. doesn't exactly equal zero, an event which occurs with the remaining probability $\gamma_{ajk}^B$, it is Normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\tau_{aj}^B$.  Combining all of this results in the first line, which if $B^*_{ajk}$ is the random variable that we actually observe, should read:

$$B^*_{ajk} \sim \gamma_{ajk}^BN(0, \tau_{aj}^B) + (1-\gamma_{ajk}^B)I_0$$

Conceptually we can think of a spike-and-slab random variable being generated through a two stage process.  The first stage determines whether the r.v. is located at the spike; this is equivalent to generating a Bernoulli variable with probability equal to the probability associated with the spike.  If the Bernoulli variate equals $1$, then we return the value corresponding to the location of the spike. If it isn't located at the spike, then it is located somewhere on the slab, and we generate (and return) a r.v. from the distribution associated with the slab. That is basically what is being implemented here, with $\gamma_{ajk}^B$ taking on the role of the first stage Bernoulli variate.

Comment: It is great to discuss this, thanks. So, is the γBajk term the likelihood and it is shrunken by the variance τBaj term (which can be variance of an inverse gamma distribution) as part of the Normal distribution, in essence shrunken by an inverse gamma distribution. This inverse gamma distribution provides the slab effect of shrinking the magnitude of the likelihood function. Then the (1−γBajk)I0 is the spike term which further shrinks the likelihood towards zero along the x instead of y direction. @jbowman

Comment: Then the  B∗ajk is the posterior of the random variable given the data informing on  γBajk and a spike and slab prior. Would you agree with these interpretations? @jbowman

Comment: A global-local shrinkage prior, which consists of a global shrinkage parameter
whose prior has substantial mass near zero to handle noise effectively, and a local shrinkage parameter whose prior has a heavy tail to avoid over-shrinkage of signals (Polson and Scott, 2010). To answer the above question